# Using "as much as" at start of sentence

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Is it correct to use "as much as" at the start of the sentence?
For example:

> As much as I like cricket, I like football.

Is it correct?

I didn't find any reference which suggest to use it that way, but only as a conjunction as in this sentence:

> I like football as much as I like cricket

Comment: What are you trying to convey? If you want to say you like both but like football more, the phrase might be "As much as I like cricket, I like football *(even) more*."

Comment: @dingo_dan i basically want to convey I like them both equally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is incorrect.

"As much as" in the beginning of a sentence is used to qualify what you do like/dislike about the statement that comes after, i.e. the first part will be A and the second part will qualify/quantify something in conflict with A

> As much as I like cricket, I dislike the waiting between innings
>
> As much as I am afraid of spiders, I love nature

Your second sentence is a correct comparison denoting you like both equally well

> I like football as much as I like cricket

---

UPDATE

The *As* may be optional, more so in British English

[image: BR]

than US

[image: US]

Comment: so in first usage, should both the statement be opposite in nature?(agree/disagree kind)

Comment: mplungian illustrates the different sub-classes available well: _As much as I like X, I'm not keen on the X1 part of it._ / _As much as I like X, I'm not keen on the Y that goes with it._ // _As much as I dislike X1, I love X in general._ / _As much as I dislike X1, I love X2._

Comment: To mplungjan: Thanks for the trouble of showing the N-grams of as much as and much as here.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a remark to mplungjan's post.

The restrictive conjunction "as much as + clause" at the beginning of a sentence is often shortened to " Much as"
- Much as I like my little sister she can sometimes be a pest.

I think this is used in British English whereas in American novels you can find "as much as".
But I have not verified this.